# Прошу помощи в программировании C# MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Имеется окно сообщения в программе типа:

```
MessageBox.Show("Имеется новая версия программы. Обновить?", "Внимание", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

С помощью `MessageBoxIcon.Information` я задаю иконку самого окна уведомления. Иконка находится в окне. 
А вот при запуске окна появляется очень некрасивая (стандартная) картинка в панели задач. Мне необходимо изменить её. Как это сделать?

Comment: *А вот при запуске окна появляется очень некрасивая (стандартная) картинка в панели задач* - прикрепите рисунок того, что Вас не устраивает. Немного не понятно, что не так.

Comment: MessageBox не отображается в панели задач, очевидно, что он тут ни причем, И конка в панели задач принадлежит форме приложения, меняйте значок там и радуйтесь красивой иконке. Просто найдите нужное свойство формы, оно даже в конструкторе отображается.

Answer (score 2):

[**MessageBox**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) - модальное информационное окно, оно не отображается в панели задач, т.к. блокирует работу приложения и может быть скрыто только другим приложением, т.о. в отдельной кнопке для MessageBox на панели задач просто нет необходимости.

Иконка в панели задач принадлежит главной форме приложения. Устанавливается иконка в свойстве [**Form.Icon**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.icon(v=vs.110).aspx). Стандартного набора иконок, кроме типовой заглушки с квадратиками, для этого свойства не предусмотрено, вам необходим специальный файл иконки `*.ico`, и да, он отличается не только расширением но и форматом, поэтому просто переименовать, например `*.jpeg` или `*.bmp` в `*.ico` не получится.

Если в приложении есть другие формы, которые запускаются с отображением на панели задач, то для них также нужно определить иконку, иначе будет использоваться дефолтная заглушка с квадратиками.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то иконка окна (именно окна, а не на форме сообщения) при вызове `MessageBox.Show()` берется из иконки приложения.
Попробуйте зайти в свойства проекта (В меню Project --> Properties, затем вкладка Application, там есть раздел Icon and manifest, укажите там иконку вашего приложения в целом.

Должно помочь.

[image: Вызов свойств через меню]

[image: Указать иконку приложения]

Comment: это иконка exe-шника. Иконка для панели задач устанавливается в каждой форме индивидуально. А MessageBox вообще не отображается в панели задач